How can I create a new branch from origin that tracks the origin branch?
I'm using Rider and looking for functionality where I can right-click a remote branch (e.g. from origin) and say 'new' and have a local branch created with its upstream automatically set to the remote branch (this is how VS operates).
However, looking at the git console, Rider issues git commands that don't automatically track the remote branch.
Rider commands:

Right-clicking and selecting checkout issues the following:
git checkout -b TestBranch origin/TestBranch1 --


Right-clicking and selecting New branch from... issues the following:
git checkout -b TestBranch origin/TestBranch1^0 --



Neither of these commands when run manually automatically track the upstream branch. I'm effectively looking for it to issue the following:
git checkout -b TestBranch origin/TestBranch1

(Note that I'm using git branch -vv to see the tracking status of each branch.)

I mentioned that that command does exactly what I want. What I’m looking for is for Rider to issue that command when I click “new branch from” or “checkout”. For some reason it issues the other two commands which result in no upstream branch being set.

Also - thanks for pointing out the mistake with 'remote-tracking'...I really meant to say 'upstream' automatically set.  I've updated the question and noted the change in the edit comments.

OK - I think I found the issue - my examples weren't 100% reflective of the problem and like always the devil is in the details.  The branches used folder-notation (e.g. features/TestBranch1).  The problem lay in the fact that the casing of the remote branch differed from my local branch (e.g. remote = FEATURES/TestBranch1, local = features/TestBranch1).  Note that I already had branches in a lower-cased 'features' folder.  Git does not automatically set upstream with -- then.  You're right @matt that -- shouldn't make a difference, but oddly it does when the casings are different.
